# Select all except first and last td element in one selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I wrote something like this in CSS:

```
tr.red > td:not(:last-of-type):not(:first-of-type)
{
    color: #E53B2C;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #E53B2C;
}
```

I'm trying to apply this to table cells, which are not first and not last in the row with `.red` class.

It seems to work as expected, but is this really the right way to do it?

Comment: Why would the code work if it was incorrect? "browsers nowadays are not sensitive for errors" <-- not sure what you mean by that, but they are also the only ones that support these selectors. You don't have to worry about if there's an IE7 bug with combining `:not(:first-of-type)` with `> td` because it won't work no matter what you do. Your syntax is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is syntactically correct, as you can quickly check using the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/). The validator is known to have errors, so in principle, you should check the rule against CSS specifications, especially [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/). The result is still that yes, it is correct.

It also has the desired meaning, since this is how selectors combine. You can use `:not(...)` selectors to express a condition of type “not ... and not ...”.

This applies provided that all children of `tr` elements are `td`. If there are header cells, i.e. `th` elements as well, then the selector applies to those data cells (`td` elements) that are not the first data cell or the last data cell in a row with `.red` class.

Comment: Thank you. I know that W3C validator is "experimetnal", thats why i was asking.

Answer (score 31):

May be this would help

```
tr.red  td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
{
//your styles
}
```

**[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNZMB/)**

Comment: There isn't really any difference here unless the table is nested.

Answer (score 10):

As some have mentioned, `td:first-child` selects the first child element of the parent `TR` if it is a `TD`, whereas `td:first-of-type` selects the first `TD` regardless of any `TH` that may come before it.

As a result, if you have any `TH` elements in your rows, your code won't give you all the cells that aren't first or last.

```
tr.red > *:not(:last-child):not(:first-child)
    { /* ... your css code ... */ }
```

I think it should work well this way. Even if you wanted to have separate code for `TH` and `TD`, you could do it like `th:not(:first-child)` and `td:not(:first-child)`.

Typically, `:first-of-type` is more intuitive when you want to style the first instance of a tag name, (like `p:first-of-type`).